# Apply for UK Standard Visa as a EU Blue card holder

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am Vietnamese, EU Blue Card holder, live in Germany and would like to travel to the UK for 10 days. As researched, I need apply for a Standard visa to able to visit UK.

My question is: What documents should I prepare to prove my financial ability and willing to back to Germany?

I am going to prepare (as in [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk)):

- A letter from employer on company headed paper, detailing my role, salary and length of employment, company contact details.
- Confirmation of legal residence
- Bank statements

Do I need to provide other documents such as Pay Stubs, Apartment Rent contract? for more informations or just 3 listed above is enough.

Thank you very much for any information!

Comment: No one can predict what other documents the consular officer would want, and it seems you already did your research and found an official source and are following the advice of that source. If they want more documents they won't simply deny the visa, they'll ask for the exact documents they want.

Comment: @Ozzy No, UKVI won’t ask for the exact documents they need, for Visitor visas a decision is made on the evidence presented at the time.

Comment: @Traveller I just received a UK visitor visa, and they did in fact ask me for a letter from my employer as additional documentation. Not sure why they wouldn't do the same in this case.

Comment: @Ozzy You’re probably right in this case. However the UK’s evidential flexibility rules https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/952663/evidential-flexibility-v11.0ext.pdf do not require UKVI to contact the applicant, or third party (e.g. the sponsor for the applicant’s job or the student sponsor ), if evidence is missing or inadequate if receiving it would make no difference to the decision. So not something to rely on IMHO

Answer (score 0):

As a German resident and an EU Blue Card holder, IMHO you do not need to go ‘over the top’ with your documentary evidence. The three types of documents you list are the most critical and should be sufficient.

However, note that contrary to the comment by @Ozzy UKVI *is highly unlikely* to ask for ‘missing documents’ for visitor visa applications, to avoid a refusal. In general, they only do that for residence-type visas.